# How to get through log in asking for phone verification?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to automate a lot of my job which requires me to log in to SalesForce (a sales management program). Since I don't want to learn all the API I want to automate it externally through xpath and stuff. The big problem is that whenever I try to log in on Salesforce, it recognizes a computer is doing the log in and asks for a verification code to my cellphone, which makes any further action absolutely unfeasible. Can someone please help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/Users/sebastiendupont/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://bus.my.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fbus.lightning.force.com%252Flightni`enter code here`ng%252Fpage%252Fhome")
xpath = '//*[@id="username"]'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys('mygmail')
xpath2 = '//*[@id="password"]'
box2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)
box2.send_keys('mypassword')
box.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra verification is intentionally added for enhanced security. There is no way you could bypass the phone authentication. However, if your application allows you to choose **Google Authenticator** instead for two factor authentication, you can generate OTP using your code.

This can be done as follows

```
pip install pyotp
```

```
totp = TOTP("put secret key here")
token = totp.now()
print(token)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, worst case do you know if there is a way to run python in a current google chrome user? The reason for that is because I'm logged off in the "guest window" that they open however I'm logged in on my chrome user

Comment: webdriver would always create a new session, so you won't be able to access it. Worst case is, you manually input the OTP from phone and then your driver continues. Which isn't scalable but there isn't much you can do here

Comment: Is there really no way to create some burner phone number that will receive an SMS and make it available to a Python scraper, without human action?